Generate Sequence of Year-Quarter in R
I have a input dataset that is like this:



Name
Date




A
2018 Q2


A
2019 Q3


B
2018 Q4


B
2019 Q4



And my desired output looks like this:



Name
Date




A
2018 Q2


A
2018 Q3


A
2018 Q4


A
2019 Q1


A
2019 Q2


A
2019 Q3


B
2018 Q4


B
2019 Q1


B
2019 Q2


B
2019 Q3


B
2019 Q4



Currently I have a for-loop (parse out Year and Quarter and keep adding 1 to start quarter until I reach the end date)
However, running the loop takes a lot of time.
I am wondering if there are any faster ways of doing this?
Thanks!

Convert to yearqtr and then use seq . Note that yearqtr represents year and quarters as the year plus 0, 1/4, 2/4 and 3/4 for the 4 quarters so using seq with by=1/4 will work.
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  mutate(Date = as.yearqtr(Date)) %>%
  reframe(Date = seq(Date[1], Date[2], 1/4), .by = Name)

giving
   Name    Date
1     A 2018 Q2
2     A 2018 Q3
3     A 2018 Q4
4     A 2019 Q1
5     A 2019 Q2
6     A 2019 Q3
7     B 2018 Q4
8     B 2019 Q1
9     B 2019 Q2
10    B 2019 Q3
11    B 2019 Q4

Note
DF <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2L),
  Date = c("2018 Q2", "2019 Q3", "2018 Q4", "2019 Q4")
)


With dplyr and tidyr you and a bit of math, you can do the following
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(Date, " Q", names = c("year", "q")) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(year, q), as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate(index=year * 4 + q-1) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  reframe(index = full_seq(index, period=1), 
          year = index %/% 4, 
          q = index %% 4+1, 
          Date = paste0(year, " Q", q)) %>% 
  select(Name, Date)

which returns
   Name  Date   
   <chr> <chr>  
 1 A     2018 Q2
 2 A     2018 Q3
 3 A     2018 Q4
 4 A     2019 Q1
 5 A     2019 Q2
 6 A     2019 Q3
 7 B     2018 Q4
 8 B     2019 Q1
 9 B     2019 Q2
10 B     2019 Q3
11 B     2019 Q4

We create a special index so we can more easily complete the sequence of year+quarter for each group.

library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  Name = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  Date = c('2018 Q2', '2019 Q3', '2018 Q4', '2019 Q4'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Function to create a sequence of quarters
create_quarter_sequence <- function(start, end) {
  start_year <- as.numeric(substr(start, 1, 4))
  start_quarter <- as.numeric(substr(start, 7, 7))
  end_year <- as.numeric(substr(end, 1, 4))
  end_quarter <- as.numeric(substr(end, 7, 7))
  
  # Create sequence of quarters
  quarters <- c()
  current_year <- start_year
  current_quarter <- start_quarter
  
  while (current_year < end_year || (current_year == end_year && current_quarter <= end_quarter)) {
    quarters <- c(quarters, paste(current_year, paste0("Q", current_quarter), sep = " "))
    current_quarter <- current_quarter + 1
    if (current_quarter > 4) {
      current_quarter <- 1
      current_year <- current_year + 1
    }
  }
  
  return(quarters)
}

# Process the data
result <- data %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(
    start_date = min(Date),
    end_date = max(Date)
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    Date = list(create_quarter_sequence(start_date, end_date))
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(Date)) %>%
  select(Name, Date)

print(result)


Actually, this is similar to an expand.grid(LETTERS[1:2], 2018:2019, paste0('Q', 1:4)). To get the factors we can use unique and substr. I think we can hard-code the quarters.
> by(df, ~Name, \(x) {
+   with(x, 
+        list(unique(Name),
+             unique(substr(Date, 1, 4)), 
+             paste0('Q', 1:4))
+   ) |> do.call(what='expand.grid') |> 
+     {\(.) transform(., Date=Reduce(paste, .[2:3]),
+                     Var2=NULL, Var3=NULL)}()  |> 
+     setNames(names(x)) |> 
+     sort_by(~list(Name, Date)) |> 
+     subset(Date >= min(x$Date) & Date <= max(x$Date))
+ }) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
   Name    Date
1     A 2018 Q2
2     A 2018 Q3
3     A 2018 Q4
4     A 2019 Q1
5     A 2019 Q2
6     A 2019 Q3
7     B 2018 Q4
8     B 2019 Q1
9     B 2019 Q2
10    B 2019 Q3
11    B 2019 Q4


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), Date = c("2018 Q2", 
"2019 Q3", "2018 Q4", "2019 Q4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

